# Child processes lost while reaping in C on linux platform

Tags: c, linux, fork

Is there any limitations on reaping number of child processes ?
let's say my system is running a parent process and 500+ child processes.

Parent is doing a waitpid(-1,status,0) in a blocking mode.
I do see sometimes waitpid returns -1.

if 500 child finishes at the same time and reports their status to the parent, is there a case a child processes can be missed ?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be such a case. What was `errno` when it returned `-1`?

Comment: Note that you might get an interrupted syscall.

Comment: When a system call returns `-1`, you should use `perror()` to print the reason.

Comment: The errorno is 10 which is ECHILD.

Comment: Are you sure there were more children still alive when ECHILD was returned, or is it possible that happened after the last child had been reaped?  Are you sure those children still had your process as their parent (e.g. they hadn't double-forked)?  Can you insert tests to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

When a system call returns an error (such as when `waitpid` returns `-1`), consult `errno` (usually via `perror`) if you need to determine what error occurred.

According to `man 2 waitpid` on my system, the possible errors are pretty limited:

- `ECHILD`: The process specified by pid does not exist or is not a child of the calling process.  (This can happen for one's own child if the action for `SIGCHLD` is set to `SIG_IGN.` See also the Linux Notes section about threads.)
- `EINTR`: `WNOHANG` was not set and an unblocked signal or a `SIGCHLD` was caught; see signal(7).
- `EINVAL`: The options argument was invalid.

Additionally, `EFAULT` could be returned if you pass a bad address for the second argument. It appears to be the case based on the code you said you used.<sup>[1]</sup>

```
waitpid(-1,status,0)
```

should be

```
waitpid(-1,&status,0)
```

If you misspoke or if you're still getting an error after fixing this problem, two possibilities are left:

- The process has no children. Any children it might have created have already been reaped.
- You setup a signal handler, and a signal came in while you were waiting for a child to end. Just call `waitpid` again.

---

1. ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings, and address them as if they were errors! With `gcc`, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: Based on a quick test, if the second argument to `waitpid` is a bad pointer, it returns `-1` and sets `errno` to `EFAULT`, instead of a segfault.  So that is one more possibility.

Comment: All the passed arguments to waitpid are correct. There is no signal handler set up. I have around 1500 child processes running. All of them exits at the same time and report their status to parent. Parent is doing a waitpid call in an infinite loop. So can it happen that some of the processes are missed while reaping?

Comment: All child processes are created by the same parent? If it would happen that a process is "missed while reaping" that would be a serious kernel bug.

Comment: @nik, No, it's not possible. /// You say you call `waitpid` in an infinite loop. What do you think happens when you call `waitpid` the 1501th time? (By the way, it's kinda silly to create that many children at once.)

Comment: Re "*I don't get how a `waitpid()` could result in a `SIGSEGV`*", Ah yes, it returns `EFAULT` in the situation I described. It felt wrong when I wrote it too X_X. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks guys. It was issue with my application. Some kind of race condition in which I called waitpid one more extra time.